# How to remove password box in checkout page and disabled email ajax call Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, address

I need to remove password box after call email ajax. I don't need this functionality while backend side guest checkout setting is on.

[image]

Comment: Do you allow customer registration in your website ?

Comment: yes, but I don't want to password box in the checkout page.

Answer (score 3):

You can overwride `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/form/element/email.js:83` file in your theme.

And force `self.isPasswordVisible(false);`

You can use this update :

```
    /**
     * Callback on changing email property
     */
    emailHasChanged: function () {
        var self = this;

        clearTimeout(this.emailCheckTimeout);

        if (self.validateEmail()) {
            quote.guestEmail = self.email();
            checkoutData.setValidatedEmailValue(self.email());
        }


        // this.emailCheckTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        //     if (self.validateEmail()) {
        //         self.checkEmailAvailability();
        //     } else {
        //         self.isPasswordVisible(false);
        //     }
        // }, self.checkDelay);
        self.isPasswordVisible(false);

        checkoutData.setInputFieldEmailValue(self.email());
    },
```